# Validating HTML form using Javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use Javascript to validate that three fields all have contents in them before proceeding to submit the form.

HTML Code:

```
<form name="form">
<input id="OldPassword" type="password">
<input id="NewPassword" type="password">
<input id="ConfirmNewPassword" type="password">
<div id="okButtonContainer">
    <span>Submit</span>
    <a href="#" onclick="validateForm()" id="submitButton">
    </a>
</div>
</form>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script>
function submitJSForm()
{
    document.getElementById('form').submit();
}

function validateForm()
{

  var a = document.getElementById("OldPassword").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("NewPassword").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("ConfirmNewPassword").value;
  alert("Got to here");
  if (a == null || a == "" || b == null || b == "" || c == null || c == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
    // do nothing
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Submitting...")
    submitJSForm();
  }
  alert("Got to end function");
}

</script>
```

All IDs match and haven't got any spelling mistakes.

Whenever I enter contents into all three fields, the if statement runs the alert "Please Fill All Required Field" which it shouldn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: value can not equal null.

Comment: Please provide some example HTML.

Comment: A tip when doing things like this, simply do console.log(a) to highlight exactly what values your fields are. It'll help with your JavaScript journey.

Comment: Show your HTML and how `submitJSForm` is called

Comment: And using required attribute can just make all of this code go away.

Comment: There we go... you're using getElementById, but none of your elements have ID's, just names.

Comment: @ChrisDixon still doesn't work when I use the IDs.

Comment: thank you @epascarello - i removed the " == null " part and it works now

Answer (score 0):

it  works  with ID, try this

```js
function submitJSForm()
{
    document.getElementById('form').submit();
}

function validateForm()
{

  var a = document.getElementById("OldPassword").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("NewPassword").value;
  var c = document.getElementById("ConfirmNewPassword").value;
  alert("Got to here");
  
  if (a == null || a == "" || b == null || b == "" || c == null || c == "")
  {
    alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
    // do nothing
  }
  else
  {
    alert("Submitting...")
    submitJSForm();
  }
  alert("Got to end function");
}
```

```html
<form name="form" id="form">
<input id="OldPassword" type="password">
<input id="NewPassword" type="password">
<input id="ConfirmNewPassword" type="password">
<div id="okButtonContainer">
  
    <a href="#" onclick="validateForm()" id="submitButton">
      <span>Submit</span>
    </a>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function called `checkValidity()`

By adding the `required` tag to each input, the following will let you know if everything is filled in inside your form

```
var form = document.getElementById(‘MyForm’);
var isValidForm = form.checkValidity();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error you got but the validation passed 
correctly here is my code based on your script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form">
        <input type="password" id="OldPassword" />
        <input type="password" id="NewPassword" />
        <input type="password" id="ConfirmNewPassword" />
        <input onclick="validateForm()" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <script>
        function submitJSForm() {
            document.getElementById('form').submit();
            alert("Submitting...");
        }

        function validateForm() {

            var a = document.getElementById("OldPassword").value;
            var b = document.getElementById("NewPassword").value;
            var c = document.getElementById("ConfirmNewPassword").value;

            if (a == null || a == "" || b == null || b == "" || c == null || c == "") {
                alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
                // do nothing
            }
            else {
                submitJSForm();
            }
        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Can you please post the HTML part of your answer ?